# Store multiline output in separate variable

Tags: bash, read

A script outputs 3 line output:

```
$ Filename /a/Resource/.Filename.man.markdown
.Filename.man.markdown
.Filename
man.markdown
```

#### What I want to do

I want to store the 3 line output in separate variable, how can I do it?

---

## I tried the following - Why it fails and how to do it correctly?

#### 1st failed attempt

```
Filename /a/Resource/.Filename.man.markdown | IFS=$'\n' read -r File1 Filename1 Extension1
echo "$File1 $Filename1 $Extension1"
```

#### 2nd Failed attempt

```bash
$ IFS=$'\n' read -r File1 Filename1 Extension1 < <(Filename /a/Resource/.Filename.man.markdown)
$ echo "$File1 $Filename1 $Extension1"
.Filename.man.markdown
```

Comment: if you're running Bash, run `help read`. It says "Reads a single line from the standard input, ...". You'll have to `read` three times to get three lines, or use `readarray` to read multiple lines into an array, or use `read -d` to tell it to use something other than the newline as the "line" terminator. (Try `read -d ''`)